# tf2 - where's quaternion_from_euler gone?

Tags: ros, python, ros-hydro, tf2, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

since I'm trying to migrate my workspace from Groovy to Hydro there are some questions arising. This is one of them. I'm going to post the others seperately.

In Python, how do I convert a vector of Euler angles into a quaternion using tf2? In tf there was something like

```
tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(...)
```

How's that done with tf2?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73819/tf2---where%27s-quaternion_from_euler-gone?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-08-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tf2 has been redesigned to provide only the functionality of tf and not bundle in external libraries for convenience.  transformations.py is an externally developed library which was included inside of tf for convenience.  For now you can continue to use it in that location. Down the road it would be cleaner to package transformations.py itself

More information on transformations.py can be found here: [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's simply in a new package, so use

```
tf_conversions.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(roll, pitch, yaw)
```

instead of

```
tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(...)
```

---

Originally posted by [vtalpaert](https://answers.ros.org/users/27555/vtalpaert/) with karma: 41 on 2016-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4